# Video from dron camera to RTSP

Tags: ros, gazebo, opencv

I am a newcomer to using ROS and am facing the challenge of obtaining a video stream from the camera topic of my robot in Gazebo and transmitting this video via RTSP. I have attempted to use the gi library, but without success.

My goal is to capture the video from the robot's camera topic in Gazebo and stream it via RTSP for further processing. I also plan to process this video and transmit it via RTSP in the future.

Has anyone in the community encountered a similar task and could share their experience or suggest suitable tools and libraries for this task?

I would appreciate any advice and assistance.

Thank you!

Comment: what's a `dron`?

Comment: i use this https://github.com/ArduPilot/ardupilot_gazebo